# Mobx @observer components and autorun renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Let's say I have two `React` components `Parent` and `Child` that are both `@observer`s of some state managed by `Mobx`. If the child uses a `Mobx` value outside of it's render method say in `componentWillReceiveProps()` will that value/observable become tracked by the parent component's render `autorun`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, unless the value is read by the parent and pass as prop value to the child

Comment: Ok great. What if the child component isn't an `@observer` class? How does Mobx `autorun` know when the parent's render method is complete? Aren't those child methods a synchronous part of the parent's render?

Comment: No they arent, so the rule of thumb is: don't pass observables to non-observer components. Instead, convert them to plain objects in the parent render (usiing slice, or mobx.toJS etc)

Comment: Sorry can you explain this a bit more, I'm a little lost. You said no they aren't snyc but then followed by what sounded like advice to avoid it.  If a non-observer child happened to use an observable, that observable could become attached to the parent's autorun? I'd just like to better understand how it works. Thank you for your help!

Comment: React renders components independently of each other, so reading a value *in* a child is not detected by the parent observer, however, passing a value *from* the parent to the child is detected (as passing props is part of the parents render)

Answer (score 0):

No it wont . Mobx just takes care of the updating the stores and wiring and the store data with the component . unless you pass the data to the child component